# Keras model.fit_generator stops/freezes in first epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm setting up a simple u-net implementation with Gipl files converted to PIL-Images. Unfortunately, after adding a DataGenerator to distribute the GPU performance more efficiently, the network stops working after initializing the first epoch without any further output.

The network generates the images for the first epoch, when I disable use_multiprocessing on the model, but runs out of memory soon. After enabeling the option again, no images are generated and no output is generated too. At least the preparation of the images should start.

The unet model:

```
model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[mean_iou])
model.summary()

params_train = {'dim': (512,512,1),
          'batch_size': 16,
          'n_classes': 2,
          'n_channels': 1,
          'shuffle': True}

X, Xv, Y, Yv = getSubsets(X_train_path, Y_train_path)

training_generator = DataGenerator(X, Y, **params_train)
validation_generator = validation_generator = DataGenerator(Xv, Yv, **params_train)  

earlystopper = EarlyStopping(patience=5, verbose=1)
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint('model-2019-1.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)# path of model
print('last output, no output of datagenerator')

model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('unet_fmr.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

results = model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    verbose=1,
                    use_multiprocessing = True,
                    epochs=30,
                    callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
```

EDITED And the DataGenerator:

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, labels, batch_size, dim, n_channels=1,
             n_classes=2, shuffle=True):
        #...initialize variables
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        indexes = self.indexes[index*self.batch_size:(index+1)*self.batch_size]

        X, Y = self.__data_generation(indexes)
        return X, Y

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) / self.batch_size))

    def on_epoch_end(self):        
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    def getImage(self, path):
        x_train_array = getGiplAsArray(path)
        x_train_i = getResizedGiplImageByArray(x_train_array)
        return x_train_i

    def make3D(self, img):
        img = np.reshape(img, (img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1))
        return img

    def __data_generation(self, indexes):
        print('__data_generation()')
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]
        list_labels_temp = [self.labels[k] for k in indexes]

        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim))
        Y = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim))

        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            temp = self.getImage(ID)
            X[i,] = self.make3D(temp)

        for i, ID in enumerate(list_labels_temp):
            temp = self.getImage(ID)
            Y[i,] = self.make3D(temp)
        return X, Y
```

The given output, ending with hours of waiting:

```
Total params: 1,940,817
Trainable params: 1,940,817
Non-trainable params: 0
initialization of DataGen
on_epoch_end()
Epoch 1/30
```

Comment: I guess the process just deadlocked. I reduced the batch_size to 8 under use_multiprocessing = False, and it works. But this still doesn't fix the problem if I want to work with a higher batch_size.